# Как у PrestaShop 1.7 отключить ограничение по символам в полном описание товара?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Как у PrestaShop 1.7 отключить ограничение по символам в полном описание товара?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак:

**1)** Заходим в базу данных и ищем «_product_lang», выбираем столбец - «description»,  в ТИП ставим: «LONGTEXT», нажимаем Сохранить.

**2)** Задаём максимальную возможную длину по символам: открываем файл ВАШДОМЕН/src/PrestaShopBundle/Form/Admin/Type/FormattedTextareaType.php

И редактируем:

```
'limit' => 21844, // size max of UTF-8 content in MySQL text column
```

На:

```
'limit' => 4294967295, // size max of UTF-8 content in MySQL text column
```

Всё!!!